# Передать JS данные в поле input, плагин ion.rangeSlider

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

Установлен плагин ion.rangeSlider, это плагин-слайдер диапозонов.

Задача такова:
Передавать JSом число которое генерит ползунок в поле input.

У меня только выходит передать их в самое содержимое div, вот код.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $range = $("#range_1"),
        $result = $("#result_1");

    var track = function (data) {
        $result.html("" + data.from);
    };

    $range.ionRangeSlider({
        type: "single",
        min: 100,
        max: 11000000,
        from: 100,
        step: 100,
        onStart: track,
        onChange: track,
        onFinish: track,
        onUpdate: track,
        prettify_enabled: true,
        postfix: " "
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо `$result = $("#some_input");` подставьте свой инпут, и дальше

```
 var track = function (data) {
   $result.val(data.from);
};
```

Comment: Благодарю...Только не работает эта фишка с моим калькулятором. Код калькулятора    <input id="result" autofocus class="form-control" style="width: initial;" type="text" name="money" size="10" maxlength="10" value="0.00" oninput="var v = this.value; this.form.new.value = isNaN(v) ? '' : (v * 1.33).toFixed (2)">  <input class="form-control" type="text" disabled="disabled" name="new" size="10" maxlength="10" value="0.00"> Необходимо вводить самим в инпут, чтобы калькулятор считал, что подскажите делать?

Comment: @Игорь вы код лучше сюда выложите https://jsfiddle.net и в вопрос добавьте его еще. А то из комментариев тяжело понимать о чем речь.

Comment: @Игорь раз уж приняли ответ в этом вопросе, создайте новый и опишите что сейчас у вас не работает. И код калькулятора добавьте в сам вопрос.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gtrftqp3/ вот калькулятор. Скриптом который в теме я должен получать скроллингом значение в инпут, работает абсолютно все кроме калькулятора, в первый инпут значение передает JS, но чтобы калькулятор сработал, необходимо произвести какое-то действие с данным инпутом (тыкнуть на него, ввести символ и прочее)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568362/js-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-input-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-oninput-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82

Answer (score 0):

Работа со значениями элементов формы, ведётся с помощью метода [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/). Вы же используеете [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)