# JS присваивает значение в INPUT, но функция oninput не срабатывает

Tags: javascript, json

Здравствуйте.

Установлен плагин ion.rangeSlider, это плагин слайдер диапозонов.

Задача такова: Передавать JSом число которое генерит ползунок в поле input (это работает). Генерируемое число приумножить на половину и вывести в другой INPUT. Все получается, число передается в инпут, но чтобы инпут начал "считать", необходимо в браузере провести с ним любое действие (добавить\убрать символ и прочее), вообщем, вопрос таков, как обойти действия с интупом? Чтобы юзер выбрал соотвествующие число и автоматом все красиво посчитало.

Скрипт здесь https://jsfiddle.net/gtrftqp3/2/

```
<form id="calc">
  <div id="1">

  <p> 
    <input id="rel" value="0.00" oninput="var v = this.value; this.form.new.value = isNaN(v) ? '' : (v * 1.50).toFixed (2)">
  </p>

  <p><p>
    <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="new" size="10" maxlength="10" value="0.00">
  </p>

  </div>
</form>

<input id="range" />

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var $range = $("#range"),
    $result = $("#rel");
    var track = function (data) {
      $result.val(data.from);
    };

    $range.ionRangeSlider({
      type: "single",
      min: 100,
      max: 1000,
      from: 100,
      step: 100,
      onStart: track,
      onChange: track,
      onFinish: track,
      onUpdate: track,
      prettify_enabled: true,
      postfix: " руб"
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Присвоение `value` элементу `input` в коде не будет вызывать событие `oninput`.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp

> The oninput event occurs when an element gets user input.

```
var track = function (data) {
  $result.val(data.from);
  if ($result[0].oninput)
    $result[0].oninput();
};
```

Comment: Заработало. Благодарю, Игорь!